# how to use bash select

Tags: bash, select

I want to create a script that can load and access the ec2 list using bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

profilelist=`cat ~/.aws/config | grep '\[profile' |  cut -f 1 -d']' | cut -f 2 -d' '`
user=`logname`

PS3='select aws account: '
select profile in $profilelist
do

ec2list=`aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=tag:stage,Values=live" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value|[0] , PrivateIpAddress]" --profile $profile --output text`

PS3='select endpoint: '
select item in $ec2list
do
        ssh $user@$item -p22
break
done
break
done
```

result

```
sh test2.sh 
1) account1
2) account2
3) account3
4) account4
select aws account: 3
1) ec2host-lv001        5) ec2host-lv003
2) 10.1.30.1            6) 10.1.30.3
3) ec2host-lv002        7) ec2host-lv004
4) 10.1.30.2            8) 10.1.30.4
```

But what I want is

```
sh test2.sh 
1) account1
2) account2
3) account3
4) account4
select aws account: 3
1) ec2host-lv001 10.1.30.1 
2) ec2host-lv002 10.1.30.2      
3) ec2host-lv003 10.1.30.3
4) ec2host-lv004 10.1.30.4
```

How can I get hostname and ip into the same line? 
Perhaps select accepts spacing as a different option

Comment: Please, edit your original post to provide a sample output from `aws ec2 describe-instances .........` command

Answer (score 1):

As you have spaces in your list you need a different separator, use something like this to use newlines

```
IFS=$'\n'
select item in $ec2list
do
        ssh $user@$item -p22
break
done
...
```

you may need to save `IFS` to be restored later if this is not the end of your script.

Also, an array might be better and add some missing quotes.
Use https://www.shellcheck.net/.

#### update

According to your comment, if you are going to replace the tab, this would be more efficient

```
ec2list=${ec2list//$'\t'/:}
```

and then

```
${item#*:}
```

to cut the ip.

Comment: I solved it like this. but your method seems neater. 
thank you.

list=`echo "$ec2list" | tr '\t' ':'`

PS3='select endpoint: '
select item in $list
do 

 ip=`echo $item | cut -d ':' -f2`
 ssh $user@$ip -p22